# even,odd,prime numbers

Tags: c++

I found even,odd,prime numbers from the read file

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv``[])
{
    ifstream read;
    read.open("input.txt");
    ofstream write;

    write.close();
    read.close();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you forgetting to reset the sums to zero when you read a new line? I honestly can't tell what you're trying to do.

Comment: sum of even number is infinity same for the odd ones. Seriously, you have to tell us what you want to do otherwise we can only blindly guess. Your code alone is perfectly fine. I think it adds up all number in the even lines and all number in the odd lines. Others guessed that you want to have the sums for the individual lines. Is this what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while (getline(read, line)){
    even = odd = 0;
    istringstream sRead(line);
    while (sRead >> x){
        if (x % 2 == 0){
            even += x;
        }
        if (x % 2 != 0){
            odd += x;
        }
    }
    write << "Sum of even numbers is: " << even << endl;
    write << "Sum of odd numbers is: " << odd << endl;
}
```

You are missing to set `even` and `odd` to 0 on each loop iteration.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're keeping the state of the summation variables between iterations.
The best way to avoid this is to declare and initialise variables as close to their use as possible.

If you want the sums line by line, use line-by-line sums:

```
   while (getline(read, line)){
        int even = 0;
        int odd = 0;
        int x = 0;
        istringstream sRead(line);
        while (sRead >> x){
            // ...
        }
    }
```